# Monitoring ALL available beacon regions using CLLocationManager

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-location

At the moment i'm doing something like the following to start getting range updates for a beacon:

```
NSUUID *uuid = [[NSUUID alloc] initWithUUIDString:@"bec26202-a8d8-4a94-80fc-9ac1de37daa6"];
self.beaconRegion = [[CLBeaconRegion alloc] initWithProximityUUID:uuid identifier:@"com.bla.bla"];
[self.locationManager startMonitoringForRegion:self.beaconRegion];
```

which is working great. but i'm wondering if there is a way to get the uuids of all beacon regions in range, and do ranging on them all, rather than me specifying the uuid.

i guess this would be possible using CoreBluetooth, manually checking the advertised services in range etc? but it would be quite complicated, nicer if CoreLocation can do it somehow.

Answer (score 1):

You can't, because that's not how you are supposed to use beacons. You are supposed to write an app that reacts to the beacons that you know about. So if I take my phone with your app running into a store or a museum full with beacons that you don't know about, nothing should happen.